# python error IndentationError: expected an indented block

Tags: 14.04, python-2.7

I started to learn python , but when I try to make an function I get this error

**IndentationError: expected an indented block**

I use the terminal and write python then start to write the function like that

```
>>> def mul (x,y) :
... ans=0
  File "<stdin>", line 2
    ans=0
      ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

so what is the wrong thing i'm doing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python uses indentation to determine the grouping of statements. You can use one or more <kbd>spaces</kbd> or one or more <kbd>tab</kbd>, just that within the same statement always use one or the other. Is recommended to use spaces instead of tabs, but is not required. Read [here](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#tabs-or-spaces)

Try:

```
>>> def mul (x,y) :
...   ans = 0
...   print ans
```

with 2 before `ans=0`.

Read [here](https://docs.python.org/2.7/) for complete documentatio of python.

Comment: can i make it by default use the spaces or the TABs just like the shell in windows

Comment: You can use spaces or tabs as you like, it makes no difference to python interpreter.

Comment: I mean , I don't want to write it my self , I need it to be written by the shell by default

Comment: python console by default doesn't offer tab completion. You can use another interactive interpreter as [ipython](http://ipython.org/), or create a script with text-editor that support indentation (eg: gedit,emacs,geany)

Answer (score 0):

Indentation Error generally occurs when there is inconsistency in the code means somewhere we have used spaces and somewhere tabs for indentation. I have got a very nice solution to this, just open your code in sublime text editor and find 'Tab Size' in bottom right corner of Sublime Text Editor and click it. Now select either

```
'Convert Indentation to Spaces'
```

OR

```
'Convert Indentation to Tabs'
```

Your code will work in either case.