# How can I reorganize files by extension, and sort them into folders by category?

Tags: command-line, scripts, python, filemanager, python3

Below code was posted by @JacobVlijm. I've tried to modify it, because I want other folder names then the file extensions, and I'd like to group file extensions into categories. The code does not work however. Please see for errors (I'm just a beginner to Python)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os
import subprocess
import shutil

# --------------------------------------------------------
reorg_dir = "/media/ashwin/Work+Entertainment/Untitled Folder"
exclude = () 
remove_emptyfolders = True
# ---------------------------------------------------------

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(reorg_dir):
    for name in files:
        subject = root+"/"+name
        if name.startswith("."):
            extension = ".hidden_files"
        elif not "." in name:
            extension = ".without_extension"
        else:
            extension = name[name.rfind("."):]
        if not extension in exclude:
        if extension==".jpeg" or extension==".jpg" or extension==".JPG" or extension==".png" or extension==".PNG":
        new_dir = reorg_dir+"/Pictures"
        elif extension==".docx" or extension==".doc" or extension==".pdf" or extension==".xlsx" or extension==".ppt" or extension==".pptx":
        new_dir = reorg_dir+"/Documents"
        elif extension==".mp3" or extension==".MP3":
        new_dir = reorg_dir+"/Songs"
        elif extension==".mp4" or extension==".MP4" or extension==".avi" or extension==".AVI":
        new_dir = reorg_dir+"/Videos"
        elif extension==".db" or extension==".DB":
        new_dir = reorg_dir+"/Databases"
        elif extension=="*.*":
        new_dir = reorg_dir+"/Others"

        if not os.path.exists(new_dir):
                os.mkdir(new_dir)
            n = 1; name_orig = name
            while os.path.exists(new_dir+"/"+name):
                name = name_orig
                n = n+1
            newfile = new_dir+"/"+name
            shutil.move(subject, newfile)

def cleanup():
    filelist = []
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(reorg_dir):
        for name in files:
            filelist.append(root+"/"+name)
    directories = [item[0] for item in os.walk(reorg_dir)]
    for dr in directories:
        matches = [item for item in filelist if dr in item]
        if len(matches) == 0:
            try:
                shutil.rmtree(dr)
            except FileNotFoundError:
                pass

if remove_emptyfolders == True:
    cleanup()
```

In this code ( posted by @Jacob Vlijm ) i've tried to add conditions to the new directories made on the extensions. But i'm getting the following error:

```
  File "filemgr.py", line 24
    new_dir = reorg_dir+"/Pictures"
          ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

Please help me out.

more errors when using python3 program.py :

```
ashwin@ashwin-X550LD:~/Project$ python filemgr.py 
ashwin@ashwin-X550LD:~/Project$ python3 filemgr.py 
  File "filemgr.py", line 23
    if extension==".jpeg" or extension==".jpg" or extension==".JPG" or extension==".png" or extension==".PNG":
                                                                                                             ^
TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation
```

Comment: See [python error IndentationError: expected an indented block](http://askubuntu.com/questions/469458/python-error-indentationerror-expected-an-indented-block)

Comment: The program gets executed without any errors when run with Python program.py.  But when using python3 program.py i get some more errors. Which to trust ? :/

Comment: No offense, but the edit of the code (http://askubuntu.com/a/516644/72216) is not very charming. I would have preferred if you' d asked a question, describing what your goal is and how you could edit the code to achieve that. I'd be happy to edit *and* explain.

Comment: Just like Jacob Vlijm - your code doesn't look nice. I'll fix it for you, make it look great and then we can all be happy. XD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add identation on that line and below. Python uses identation to identify code blocks and the code below the if statement should be identated since it belongs to the if block. Standard identation acording to PEP8 is 4 spaces.

Answer (score 2):

#### What you actually want

Looking at your edit, what you actually want is to create the folders:

**Pictures

Documents

Songs

Videos

Database

Others**

Instead of the folders, named after the extensions, like in the [original script](https://askubuntu.com/a/516644/72216).

#### The principle

The first rule is always: if you do the same thing more than once, make it a function. Repeating the same thing is unnecessarily verbose, makes your code difficult to maintain (change), exhaustive to read and look ugly.

Using a *function*, instead of:

```py
if extension==".jpeg" or extension==".jpg" or extension==".JPG" or extension==".png" or extension==".PNG":
new_dir = reorg_dir+"/Pictures"
elif extension==".docx" or extension==".doc" or extension==".pdf" or extension==".xlsx" or extension==".ppt" or extension==".pptx":
new_dir = reorg_dir+"/Documents"
elif extension==".mp3" or extension==".MP3":
new_dir = reorg_dir+"/Songs"
elif extension==".mp4" or extension==".MP4" or extension==".avi" or extension==".AVI":
new_dir = reorg_dir+"/Videos"
elif extension==".db" or extension==".DB":
new_dir = reorg_dir+"/Databases"
elif extension=="*.*":
    new_dir = reorg_dir+"/Others"
```

You can use:

```py
def dir_names(ext):
    extensions = [
        [["jpeg", "jpg", "png"], "Pictures"],
        [["mp4", "avi"], "Videos"],
        [["docx", "doc", "pdf", "xlsx", "ppt", "pptx"], "Documents"],
        [["mp3"], "Songs"],
        [["db"], "Database"],
        ]
    match = [item[1] for item in extensions if ext.lower() in item[0]]
    return match[0] if match else "Others"
```

To "calculate" the targeted folder names. Subsequently apply the function in the line:

```py
extension = dir_names(name[name.rfind(".")+1:]) # edited line
```

#### The whole script then becomes:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os
import subprocess
import shutil

# --------------------------------------------------------
reorg_dir = "/media/ashwin/Work+Entertainment/Untitled Folder"
exclude = () # for example
remove_emptyfolders = True
# ---------------------------------------------------------

def dir_names(ext):
    extensions = [
        [["jpeg", "jpg", "png"], "Pictures"],
        [["mp4", "avi"], "Videos"],
        [["docx", "doc", "pdf", "xlsx", "ppt", "pptx"], "Documents"],
        [["mp3"], "Songs"],
        [["db"], "Database"],
        ]
    match = [item[1] for item in extensions if ext.lower() in item[0]]
    return match[0] if match else "Others"

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(reorg_dir):
    for name in files:
        subject = root+"/"+name
        if name.startswith("."):
            extension = "hidden_files"
        elif not "." in name:
            extension = "without_extension"
        else:
            extension = dir_names(name[name.rfind(".")+1:]) # edited line
        if not extension in exclude:
            new_dir = reorg_dir+"/"+extension
            if not os.path.exists(new_dir):
                os.mkdir(new_dir)
            shutil.move(subject, new_dir+"/"+name)

def cleanup():
    filelist = []
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(reorg_dir):
        for name in files:
            filelist.append(root+"/"+name)
    directories = [item[0] for item in os.walk(reorg_dir)]
    for dr in directories:
        matches = [item for item in filelist if dr in item]
        if len(matches) == 0:
            try:
                shutil.rmtree(dr)
            except FileNotFoundError:
                pass

if remove_emptyfolders == True:
    cleanup()
```

#### Explanation on the function

```py
def dir_names(ext):
    extensions = [
        [["jpeg", "jpg", "png"], "Pictures"],
        [["mp4", "avi"], "Videos"],
        [["docx", "doc", "pdf", "xlsx", "ppt", "pptx"], "Documents"],
        [["mp3"], "Songs"],
        [["db"], "Database"],
        ]
    match = [item[1] for item in extensions if ext.lower() in item[0]]
    return match[0] if match else "Others"
```

- `extension` is a list, of which every list item exists of a sublist of ectensions (lower case) and the corresponding folder you'd like to move it to.
- The function simply checks if the extension (lower) is in the extensions list, then returns the corresponding (desired) folder name.
- If the extension is not in the extension list of *any* of the sub lists, the function returns `Others`.

#### Why your code does not work

Apart from the issue of inefficient coding, the proposed code has some other issues, of which indentation is the most important. (after `if/else` you *must* indent, *or* use a line like:

```
monkey = animal if 1 == 1 else vegetable
```

)

In python, indentation is essential.

Running `python` code, errors are usually mentioned by the interpreter in a pretty readable format. Always start reading error messages from down upwards.

Comment: Thank you @Jacob Vlijm. Really appreciate your help. !! :)

Comment: the above code generates a random tk window when i use tkFileDialog for getting the reorg_dir from the user. Why does it get created when i haven't written it's code ?

Comment: @AshwinJoshi I have no idea in what construction you use the script, but it needs a *directory* as input, not a file.

Answer (score 1):

Python is whitespace sensitive, this means you have to indent code correctly; otherwise you'll get errors...

After an `if` block, you need to indent the code, you can use <kbd>Tab</kbd> to do this.

Your code should look like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os
import subprocess
import shutil

# --------------------------------------------------------
reorg_dir = "/media/ashwin/Work+Entertainment/Untitled Folder"
exclude = () 
remove_emptyfolders = True
# ---------------------------------------------------------

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(reorg_dir):
    for name in files:
        subject = root+"/"+name
        if name.startswith("."):
            extension = ".hidden_files"
        elif not "." in name:
            extension = ".without_extension"
        else:
            extension = name[name.rfind("."):]
        if not extension in exclude:
            if extension==".jpeg" or extension==".jpg" or extension==".JPG" or extension==".png" or extension==".PNG":
                new_dir = reorg_dir+"/Pictures"
            elif extension==".docx" or extension==".doc" or extension==".pdf" or extension==".xlsx" or extension==".ppt" or extension==".pptx":
                new_dir = reorg_dir+"/Documents"
            elif extension==".mp3" or extension==".MP3":
                new_dir = reorg_dir+"/Songs"
            elif extension==".mp4" or extension==".MP4" or extension==".avi" or extension==".AVI":
                new_dir = reorg_dir+"/Videos"
            elif extension==".db" or extension==".DB":
                new_dir = reorg_dir+"/Databases"
            elif extension=="*.*":
                new_dir = reorg_dir+"/Others"

        if not os.path.exists(new_dir):
                os.mkdir(new_dir)
            n = 1; name_orig = name
            while os.path.exists(new_dir+"/"+name):
                name = name_orig
                n = n+1
            newfile = new_dir+"/"+name
            shutil.move(subject, newfile)

def cleanup():
    filelist = []
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(reorg_dir):
        for name in files:
            filelist.append(root+"/"+name)
    directories = [item[0] for item in os.walk(reorg_dir)]
    for dr in directories:
        matches = [item for item in filelist if dr in item]
        if len(matches) == 0:
            try:
                shutil.rmtree(dr)
            except FileNotFoundError:
                pass

if remove_emptyfolders == True:
    cleanup()
```